# Decode base64 converted image on server show corrupt image

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, base64, afnetworking

I'm converting an image from gallery to base64, then upload it to 'webServices.asmx'.
The image get corrupt on server, or is it my fault? I don't know.
I tried to put the string in: 'http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html' and decode the string and get the correct image.

My code:

```
// HTTP POST
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
        [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", userID], @"userID",
                                self.imageBase64, @"file",
                                nil];


        [httpClient postPath:@"http://www....../webServices.asmx/saveImageIOS" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"\nResponse XML: \n%@", responseString);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }];
```

Sample base64 string(converted image):

> 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

**EDIT:**
The problem was server side, fixed for now, my code was pretty fine (even when duplicated userID, which I removed). :)

Comment: Is the server actually expecting the image to be uploaded as a form parameter base64 format? Or is it expecting a vanilla file attachment? If so, you are using the wrong `AFHTTPClient` method.

Comment: It's probably not the issue, but you seem to be sending the userID parameter twice.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, just saw it and fixed it, maybe this was the problem.

Comment: @AlexMDC, yes, the server expecting base64 format.